# Providing dynamic data to webpage

Tags: php

I have a web page that displays dynamic data which changes every 2 seconds. Data is selected from various data sources including Oracle. Currently, the page reloads every 10 seconds and runs a PHP script which retrieves the data and displays the page. I have other pages that gives a different view on the same data. This means the same query is run again for them as well. If I have 4 of these pages with 10 concurrent users each, suddenly the data retrieval happens 40 times every 10 seconds, obviously not ideal. I have some ideas on how to improve this situation, but I thought I would ask from some ideas from other experts that might have come across a similar situation. I'm not bound to PHP, and my server is on a Linux platform.

Regards

Marius

Comment: Hi Marius, if you let us know your ideas we can help more effectively.

Comment: Matt: My idea was to create a small daemon that would fetch the data and provide it to requester via a socket or shared memory interface. This sounds a bit like what memchache is doing which has been suggested by Kamil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in a recent project and opted to cache all the retrieved database data using a [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) daemon. So instead of querying the database 40 times you will query it once and then subsequently simply open a TCP/IP connection to the memcached daemon to fetch the cached result data. Note that PHP has a memcached extension which is quite easy to understand and use.

If the page you display to the user must update its data every 2 seconds or so then it might be best to reload the data via AJAX instead of loading the HTML, CSS and Javascript every time the page gets refreshed. Taha above mentioned using a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) server to simulate 'pushing' the data from the server to the client. You can easily roll your own. From my understanding the two main techniques that will work with all major browsers are:

- AJAX long-polling, where the AJAX request only completes once new data is available to show (this is the method I ended up using).
- Loading a never-ending page in an IFRAME.

An excellent tutorial for using the above two techniques is availabe [here](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start). The author also provides their code for download.

Although I used Apache + PHP to implement my Comet solution, it might be better to switch to a non-blocking framework such as [Tornado (Python)](http://www.tornadoweb.org/).

Comment: Thanks, it seems Memcached is the way to go to start with. I was going to change the page reloading to use AJAX anyway, so I will be looking into long polling and Comet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cache retrieved data in memcache for few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from improving your data structures and methods of query you need to start looking at caching at all the different levels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to run a cron job to keep a single local copy up to date 24x7....

Store the data locally along with the time it was fetched. If, when a request is received, the data is considered stale, raise a mutex before fetching the data - this also means that the script should check for a mutex before trying to refresh the cache.

Note that PHP does not have sophisticated file locking sematics - so I'd recommend storing the local data in a database. Note that AFAIK there is no non-blocking lock mechanism within PHP nor one which provides for timeouts - so you'll probably need to roll your own.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your requirement i would suggest you use a comet server.

Check this thread for details [solution for COMET and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961206/solution-for-comet-and-php/2386803#2386803)

You can check few examples at the following links

[APE Project](http://www.ape-project.org/ajax-push.html)

[Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/products.htm)

[Liberator](http://www.freeliberator.com/comet/)

Answer (score 0):

Re my other answer here -

You can avoid the mutex problem by:

Have a cron'ed script that checks the mtime on a control file - if it has been updated in the N minutes, run a collection to the local copy.

In the web page script, if the local data is stale, return a message saying its refreshing the data, update the control file. If the local data is not stale, show it AND update the control file.

C.