# In-Site Instant Messaging-Framework?

Tags: php, instant-messaging

Is there any instant messaging framework or service that enables in-site chatting like the Facebook chat-bar or the Meebo bar?

Comment: Have you tried [Ajax IM](http://ajaxim.com/)?

Comment: I've already tried it, but the documentation is not finished and there are still many bugs?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a solution now named CometChat, which is a commercial product.

http://www.cometchat.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read about COMET. For making your own instant messaging system.

You can find more information on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned this could be implemented via a technique called [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). (The term was coined by Alex Russell in a [blog entry](http://infrequently.org/2006/03/comet-low-latency-data-for-the-browser/).) But PHP does not seem to be very well suited for this technique as already discussed on StackOverflow:

- [Using comet with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)
- [How to implement a chat room using Jquery/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174521/how-to-implement-a-chat-room-using-jquery-php)
- [solution for COMET and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961206/solution-for-comet-and-php)

You should have a look at these threads because they also provide further explanations as well as hints for solutions or alternativ implementations.