# zend framework and comet programming

Tags: php, zend-framework, comet

I want to use comet programming with zend framework, but zend framework uses only one single file for processing a request while in comet I need to process 2 requests at the same time. As in zend only a single file is used to handle the request if any other request is used then it will be put in queue state.

If 2 different files are taken by changing the request .htaccess file then session_id is not constant or varies.

How do I overcome the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you have a look at:

- [Using comet with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)
- [solution for COMET and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961206/solution-for-comet-and-php)

There isn't a good solution for PHP. IMHO the best option would be to use your PHP server with Zend framework for your web app. And use a different server for your realtime web infrastructure. This means you can either use a [self hosted](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted) or [hosted realtime solution](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services).

Comment: thankx leggetter. I think I have to go with sub-domain for the solution.

Comment: Ok, a self hosted solution is the way to go. I'd go with a dedicated realtime server and communicate between it and your web application using queues and/or web service calls.