# What is the easiest way to implement a Comet serverside backend?

Tags: php, python, http, comet, push

PHP as an Apache module or otherwise, [would start one thread per pending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php) so it doesn't scale well.

Are Java and Python my only other options?

As a complete newbie to Python, is Twisted easy to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twisted is very powerful but not easy to use, especially for a newbie.

[tornado](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Sep/10/tornado/) is another async server in Python, less general than Twisted (you would not use it for a network *client* for example) but simpler to use to implement servers, including Comet ones.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). It's an evented server-side framework using JavaScript. It will not block communication with your browsers, since it's event-driven.

Comment: Does it keep recompiling the javascript source code everytime a request is recieved?

Comment: Node.js runs on top of the V8 js engine - so I imagine it gets interpreted only once.

Answer (score 1):

My experience, been absolutely newbie with Twisted is that you can implement Comet easily with It. I've used [Athena](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow/Athena), which is included in [Nevow](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow). Nevow is built on top of Twisted. It's third pary.

Give it a try.

Here is an [example](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow/Athena/Tutorials/LiveElement).