# PHP and AJAX, sending new PHP info to page for AJAX to receive, is this possible?

Tags: php, javascript, asynchronous

I'm searching on how to do this but my searches aren't turning up things that are talking about what I'm trying to do so maybe I'm not searching with the right terms or this isn't possible, but figured I would ask here for help.. this is what I am trying to do..

I have PHP scripts that are called asyncrhonously, so it is called and it just runs, the calling PHP doesn't wait for a response, so it can go on to do other stuff / free things up so another asynch php process can be run.

I would still like to get back a result from these "zombie" scripts or whatever you want to call them, however the only way I can think of doing it that I know for sure will work is something like make this "zombie" script save its final output to a database and then have my AJAX UI make periodic requests to this database to check if the needed value exists in the place it is supposed to.. which would allow it to get the output from the zombie PHP script..

I am thinking it would be better if somehow this zombie script could do a sort of page refresh to the AJAX ui but the ajax ui would intercept this and just take the received data from PHP and use it as needed (such as display in a DIV for user to see).. basically I'm wondering if you can make PHP force this kind of thing rather than needing to involve a database in this and making AJAX do repeated requests to check for a specific value that way..

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a background script has no way to influence the client's front-end because it has no connection to it.

Starting a background script, having the script write status data into a shared space - be it a database or a memcache or a similar solution - and polling the status through Ajax is usually indeed the best way to go.

One alternative may be [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). It's a technique where a connection is kept open over a long time, and updated actively from the server side (instead of frequent client-side Ajax polling). I have no practical experience with this but I imagine it most probably needs server side tweaking to be doable in PHP - it's not the best platform for long-running stuff. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php) for some approaches.