# How to implement a chat room using Jquery/PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-polling

I'm looking to implement a chat room using PHP/Javascript (Jquery) with both group chat and private chat features.

The problem is how to continually update the interface in a natural way and possibly also how to show 'X is typing..' messages in private chat.

The obvious way seems to be that every X seconds/milliseconds the javascript pings the server and fetches a list of new messages between the last ping and now. However, this can make the interface seem a bit unnatural, if suddenly the chat room is flooded with 5 messages. I would rather each message appear as it is typed.

Is there a way for javascript to maintain a continuous connection to the server, the server pushes any new messages to this connection, and javascript adds them to the interface so they appear simultaneously, almost as soon as the server receives them?

I know there are some polling options that require you to install some apache modules etc, but I'm pretty bad of a sysadmin, therefore I'd prefer if there was a very easy to install solution on a shared hosting account, or a php/mysql only solution.

Comment: `PHP in CLI=Yes`, `PHP in HTTP call=No`, `PHP + Javascript=Possible cause JavaScript can fire multi requests`

Comment: @Ajreal - Would appreciate if you could post some sample code to show how it can be done

Comment: I was actually looking at this today:
http://css-tricks.com/chat2/

It doesn't auto update, but it definitely provides a background for a PHP/jQuery chatroom.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Chat with PHP/AJAX/JSON

I used this book/tutorial to write my chat application:

[AJAX and PHP: Building Responsive Web Applications: Chapter 5: AJAX chat and JSON](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/AJAXChatJSON.aspx).

It shows how to write a complete chat script from scratch.

---

## Comet based chat

*You can also use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) with [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php).*

From: [zeitoun](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start):

Comet enables web servers to send data to the client without having any need for the client to request it. Therefor, this technique will produce more responsive applications than classic AJAX. In classic AJAX applications, web browser (client) cannot be notified in real time that the server data model has changed. The user must create a request (for example by clicking on a link) or a periodic AJAX request must happen in order to get new data fro the server.

I'll show you two ways to implement Comet with PHP. For example:

1. based on hidden `<iframe>` using server timestamp
2. based on a classic AJAX non-returning request

The first shows the server date in real time on the clients, the displays a mini-chat.

#### Method 1: iframe + server timestamp

You need:

- a backend PHP script to handle the persistent http request `backend.php`
- a frondend HTML script load Javascript code `index.html`
- the [prototype JS library](http://www.prototypejs.org/), but you can also use jQuery

The backend script (`backend.php`) will do an infinite loop and will return the server time as long as the client is connected.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sun, 5 Mar 2012 05:00:00 GMT");
flush();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Comet php backend</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// KHTML browser don't share javascripts between iframes
var is_khtml = navigator.appName.match("Konqueror") || navigator.appVersion.match("KHTML");
if (is_khtml)
{
  var prototypejs = document.createElement('script');
  prototypejs.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
  prototypejs.setAttribute('src','prototype.js');
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
  head[0].appendChild(prototypejs);
}
// load the comet object
var comet = window.parent.comet;
</script>

<?php
while(1) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'comet.printServerTime('.time().');';
    echo '</script>';
    flush(); // used to send the echoed data to the client
    sleep(1); // a little break to unload the server CPU
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The frontend script (`index.html`) creates a "comet" javascript object that will connect the backend script to the time container tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Comet demo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">The server time will be shown here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var comet = {
connection   : false,
iframediv    : false,

initialize: function() {
  if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {

    // For IE browsers
    comet.connection = new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");
    comet.connection.open();
    comet.connection.write("<html>");
    comet.connection.write("<script>document.domain = '"+document.domain+"'");
    comet.connection.write("</html>");
    comet.connection.close();
    comet.iframediv = comet.connection.createElement("div");
    comet.connection.appendChild(comet.iframediv);
    comet.connection.parentWindow.comet = comet;
    comet.iframediv.innerHTML = "<iframe id='comet_iframe' src='./backend.php'></iframe>";

  } else if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("KHTML") != -1) {

    // for KHTML browsers
    comet.connection = document.createElement('iframe');
    comet.connection.setAttribute('id',     'comet_iframe');
    comet.connection.setAttribute('src',    './backend.php');
    with (comet.connection.style) {
      position   = "absolute";
      left       = top   = "-100px";
      height     = width = "1px";
      visibility = "hidden";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(comet.connection);

  } else {

    // For other browser (Firefox...)
    comet.connection = document.createElement('iframe');
    comet.connection.setAttribute('id',     'comet_iframe');
    with (comet.connection.style) {
      left       = top   = "-100px";
      height     = width = "1px";
      visibility = "hidden";
      display    = 'none';
    }
    comet.iframediv = document.createElement('iframe');
    comet.iframediv.setAttribute('src', './backend.php');
    comet.connection.appendChild(comet.iframediv);
    document.body.appendChild(comet.connection);

  }
},

// this function will be called from backend.php  
printServerTime: function (time) {
  $('content').innerHTML = time;
},

onUnload: function() {
  if (comet.connection) {
    comet.connection = false; // release the iframe to prevent problems with IE when reloading the page
  }
}
}
Event.observe(window, "load",   comet.initialize);
Event.observe(window, "unload", comet.onUnload);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Method 2: AJAX non-returning request

You need the same as in method 1 + a file for dataexchange (`data.txt`)

Now, backend.php will do 2 things:

1. Write into "data.txt" when new messages are sent
2. Do an infinite loop as long as "data.txt" file is unchanged

> ```
> <?php
> $filename  = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.txt';
>
> // store new message in the file
> $msg = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : '';
> if ($msg != '')
> {
>     file_put_contents($filename,$msg);
>     die();
> }
>
> // infinite loop until the data file is not modified
> $lastmodif    = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
> $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
> while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) // check if the data file has been modified
> {
>     usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
>     clearstatcache();
>     $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
> }
>
> // return a json array
> $response = array();
> $response['msg']       = file_get_contents($filename);
> $response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
> echo json_encode($response);
> flush();
> ?>
> ```

The frontend script (`index.html`) creates the `<div id="content"></div>` tags hat will contains the chat messages comming from "data.txt" file, and finally it create a "comet" javascript object that will call the backend script in order to watch for new chat messages.

The comet object will send AJAX requests each time a new message has been received and each time a new message is posted. The persistent connection is only used to watch for new messages. A timestamp url parameter is used to identify the last requested message, so that the server will return only when the "data.txt" timestamp is newer that the client timestamp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Comet demo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
</div>

<p>
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="comet.doRequest($('word').value);$('word').value='';return false;">
  <input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Comet = Class.create();
Comet.prototype = {

timestamp: 0,
url: './backend.php',
noerror: true,

initialize: function() { },

connect: function()
{
  this.ajax = new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
    method: 'get',
    parameters: { 'timestamp' : this.timestamp },
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
      // handle the server response
      var response = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
      this.comet.timestamp = response['timestamp'];
      this.comet.handleResponse(response);
      this.comet.noerror = true;
    },
    onComplete: function(transport) {
      // send a new ajax request when this request is finished
      if (!this.comet.noerror)
        // if a connection problem occurs, try to reconnect each 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){ comet.connect() }, 5000); 
      else
        this.comet.connect();
      this.comet.noerror = false;
    }
  });
  this.ajax.comet = this;
},

disconnect: function()
{
},

handleResponse: function(response)
{
  $('content').innerHTML += '<div>' + response['msg'] + '</div>';
},

doRequest: function(request)
{
  new Ajax.Request(this.url, {
    method: 'get',
    parameters: { 'msg' : request 
  });
}
}
var comet = new Comet();
comet.connect();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

## Alternatively

You can also have a look at other chat applications to see how they did it:

- http://hot-things.net/?q=blite - BlaB! Lite is an AJAX based and best viewed with any browser chat system that supports MySQL, SQLite & PostgreSQL databases.
- [Gmail/Facebook Style jQuery Chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)  - This jQuery chat module enables you to seamlessly integrate Gmail/Facebook style chat into your existing website.
- [Writing a JavaScript/PHP Chat Server](http://code.jenseng.com/jenChat/) - A tutorial
- [CometChat](http://www.cometchat.com/) - CometChat runs on standard shared servers. Only PHP + mySQL required.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this code, however with the Iframe method, if I use flush(), in google chrome I don't see a response immediately, only when the page has finished loading?

Comment: You need to keep the connection alive. The second method uses 'long polling'. Also see the comments: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start.

Comment: I just found Ajax Chat; an open source web chat application using ajax, sockets, php and ruby (last is optional): https://blueimp.net/ajax/

Comment: `I'd prefer if there was a very easy to install solution on a shared hosting account, or a php/mysql only solution.`, I suggest you to use push services to make the chatting environment even better. (With push, your client doesn't have to request the server to get new data + it makes the chatting real-time.) Some push services with good a documentation and libraries: http://beaconpush.com, http://pusherapp.com, http://kwwika.com

Comment: How to implement the data.txt file if I want to be able to hold multiple chat sessions?

Answer (score 5):

Polling is not a good idea.  You need a solution that use long polling or web sockets.

http://hookbox.org is probably the best tool you can use.

It is a box that lives between the server and the browsers and manages abstractions called channels (think about an IRC channel).  It is open source on github: https://github.com/hookbox/hookbox The box is written in Python but it can easily be used with a server written in any language. It also come with a Javascript library that is built on jsio (uses websockets, long-polling, or whatever is the best technology available on the browser) that guarantee that it uses the best technology available in the browsers.In a demo I saw a **realtime chat** implemented  with few line of code.

Hookbox’s purpose is to ease the development of real-time web applications, with an emphasis on tight integration with existing web technology. Put simply, Hookbox is a web-enabled message queue. Browers may directly connect to Hookbox, subscribe to named channels, and publish and receive messages on those channels in real-time. An external application (typically the web application itself) may also publish messages to channels by means of the Hookbox REST interface. All authentication and authorization is performed by an external web application via designated “webhook” callbacks.

[image]

Any time a user connects or operates on a channel, ( subscribe, publish, unsubscribe) Hookbox makes an http request to the web application for authorization for the action. Once subscribed to a channel, the user’s browser will receive real-time events that originate either in another browser via the javascript api, or from the web application via the REST api.

They key insight is that all application development with hookbox Happens either in javascript, or in the native language of the web application itself (e.g. PHP.)

You need a server that can run Python BUT you do NOT have to know Python.

If instead you want to use just websockets and PHP this is good starting point: http://blancer.com/tutorials/69066/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [PHPDaemon](http://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon), which is written with active usage of libevent and pnctl? [It](http://phpdaemon.net/) has lots of features and even simple [chat](http://phpdaemon.net/examples/simplechat/) demo application. Even it has some production implementations.

Comment: That's very interesting, it seems like it'll get the job done. But can it be installed on a shared hosting? I wasn't clear from the documentation on where i need to upload the code to be able to run the installation command using SSH (I assume)

Comment: PHPDeamon is a backend server solution and therefor not a good solution for a shared hosting account.

Answer (score 2):

this could be a good starting point

http://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to implement it with HTML5 WebSockets, with long polling or comet as a fallback for older browsers. WebSockets open a persistent connection to the browser.
There is an open source [php implementation of a websocket server](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) together with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). Socket.IO gives you a nice and very easy client API, works on most modern browsers and uses appropriate transport where possible (Websocket, long polling, etc). NodeJS is a server-side daemon, which holds HTTP connections. Official site of the Socket.IO contains information on how to use them together. Hope it will help you.

Comment: NodeJS requires Python 2.4 or better, not PHP

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are looking at requires the use of comet web programming. You can find more details on wikipedia, by searching for Comet programming, and on Ajaxian (I'm still new to this site and I can't post more than 1 link in the response).

The problem is that this can't be easily achieved with php on the server side. More details:
[using comet with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)

Also, if you search on google for 'php comet' you'll find a tutorial to achieve the desired effect.

**LATER EDIT**

[Ape project](http://www.ape-project.org/demos/1/ape-real-time-chat.html)

Implemented a project using this engine. Is great.

[Comet with php](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

Hope this helps,
Gabriel

Comment: I've been digging into APE and there seem to be some nasty problems with it, although it's considered 'stable'. See: http://www.nulldevice.de/2010/09/ape-ajax-push-engine/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and for the link. I've also experienced some of that problems.

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising! Might even be super easy to restyle :)

> http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/ajax-chat.php

## Ajax Chat script in Javascript/PHP

#### Description

> Ajax Chat is a light-weight customizable web chat software implemented in JavaScript and PHP. The script does not require Java, Flash, or any other plugins.

#### Features

- Public and private chat.
- Login as a registered user or as a guest.
- Away status, custom colors, smileys, user gender/status icons.
- Ajax Chat can be integrated with a third-party membership system by implementing user authentication routine. Advanced integration options: if user is logged in to the website, he can be logged in to the chat automatically.

[image: Ajax lightweight chat script]

*Please note that this is a copy/paste from [the original site](http://www.php-development.ru/javascripts/ajax-chat.php).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it with PHP before but you're best bet would probably be some kind of socket connection. Here's the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=socket&lang=en) for sockets.

I don't remember who's tutorial it was but I made a chat room like what you want using Flash for the client and Java for the server. I think [this link](http://ec2-50-16-39-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com/blog/?p=205) might be where the tutorial was and it may help you out.

Comment: I don't think sockets would be much use with this. The sockets would have to connect to something, ie, the users would have to have something in their computers that would allow the connection

Comment: How do you mean? When I did it with Flash it could be embedded in the browser and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway : flash is NOT a web page (text, HTML), is a binary program

Comment: @ajreal: Hmmm I don't remember saying that Flash is a web page? It was embedded in HTML on a web page.

Comment: Perhaps the socket could be connected to the javascript?

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway - embed flash in HTML is like telling browser `Hey, i need u to run this program`, and browser said `OK, i will do it`, and after browser happily started flash, flash said `haha, i want to call Irene first`, later flash said `now i want to call Steve`, and so on...and it can continuously calling because the program is NOT ended

Comment: @Aaron: Flash can run continuously while php execution ends when the script ends (there are ways to keep a php script running forever but I don't think it would be much use in this situation)