# Chat box creation  HTML/dynamic web/jquery Ajax 

Tags: html, css, jquery, chat

Can somebody show me how to create a chat box in HTML ? I'm using jquery and Ajax for a dynamic webpage. I tried to use the input text box but I don't know how to have another chat box to post the session from both parties in it.

LS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a chat room using Jquery/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174521/how-to-implement-a-chat-room-using-jquery-php)

Answer (score 2):

Just have a DIV that is dynamically updated by your javascript.

You can also find numerable tutorials for this via google. Like this one [here](http://www.gamexe.net/other/jquery-chatbox/)

In particular, this little section of JQuery will give you an idea to work from:

```
function LoadNewMessages() {
  // Loads new messages from retrieve_new.php file into new_posts div
   $('#new_posts').load("retrieve_new.php");

   // Determines whether or not there is a new message by searching new_posts div
    if (document.getElementById('new_posts').innerHTML != '') {

    // If nothing exists it won't do anything but if there is it will post this:
     $('#chatbox').prepend("
"+document.getElementById('new_posts').innerHTML+"
");

    // This makes it fade in. Not necessary but cool.
     $('#new_message').fadeIn(1000);

    // Empties the div for future posts.
     $('#actions').html("");
   }
}
// Refreshes and checks for new messages.
setInterval("LoadNewMessages();", 1000);
```