# How to get realtime data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, real-time

I am trying to build a bus application which shall behave exactly like this (http://pdxlivebus.com/) one.

Now I simply can not get the idea out that how can i constantly feed data to the UI from my backend? I don't want to send ajax requests after some intervals. I have done chat application with react and node.js but they are realtime in a sense that one user does something(send message or disconnect) and for that the server sends out a socket event and the client listens and updates.

But application like this one http://pdxlivebus.com/ where the user does not do anything but to watch the buses how does the UI gets updated with the latest data?

Comment: They're using websockets, with the [socket.io](https://socket.io/) library

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How to get realtime updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6304937/218196)

Comment: I know they are using websockets i have seen it in network traffic but my question is how they managed to emit the data and receive the data with out any action from client?

Comment: *"with out any action from client?"* Well, they don't. The client has to establish the websocket connection. But that can be done without *user interaction*.

Comment: you have a pushing server script run every 15 seconds or so, there's no need to be ultra-precise.

Comment: @FelixKling yes after establishing how do i get the data without calling some function like setinterval from client

Comment: The server simply sends data via the socket.

Comment: This is _wayyyyy_ too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally http://pdxlivebus.com/ is using [socket.io](http://socket.io) – check line no. 23178 of http://pdxlivebus.com/dist/bundle.js

[image: part of source code with marked line]

Emitted event `vehicle_update` returns data like:

```
{
  "routeNumber": 100,
  "delay": -37,
  "inCongestion": null,
  "latitude": 45.5231087,
  "longitude": -122.959265,
  "type": "rail",
  "vehicleID": 104
}
```

With information like that you can build animations for each element (vehicleID is uniq, it is easy to track) that is in move.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understood this app uses websockets. There is a event that the server emits and the client receives. My question is how can I ensure there is always an event going on so that the client can keep listening and updating the data?

Comment: You want to have that knowledge on back or front-end side? Backand can track all connected clients - if response from client is missing - it means lack of connection with it. Some kind of heartbeat - after each (or less, e.g after 100 ticks) send response to backend that client is still connected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to integrate real-time database.
You can use Firebase database https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Here is sample code on how to integrate it.
https://moquet.net/blog/realtime-geolocation-tracking-firebase/

Comment: but I will be getting the data from an api!

Comment: You have two options now.
1. Use [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) fetch data from API and update your Firebase real time data.

2. Use [MEAN stack](http://meanjs.org/), you can skip angularjs but use other with [Socketio](https://socket.io/)
Keep some interval to fetch latest location data after every 5 sec or so and update your vehicle tracking table which subscribed by each client using [Socketio](https://socket.io/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webrtc](https://webrtc.org/) which is a enables the real time comunication between browser.

Or

You can go with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) which enables the realtime, bi-directional communication between web clients and server

Answer (score 1):

**Use set interval method**

```js
const [time, setTime] = React.useState("Time");
```

```js
  function currentTime() {
    let Time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

    setTime(Time);
    setInterval(currentTime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with sockets, maybe you can work with [socket.io](https://socket.io/) other great library is [SuperWebSocket](https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) is compatible with .net and html5.

And for the client i think the best option is [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/), is a powerful tool for work with real time data, for example this [web](http://livexll.com/livebet.asp) use Angularjs for show real time data