# How to provide a pair of users with same website content

Tags: php, ajax

I am designing a game, where two users at a time are provided with same questions one after other. However each user has to wait until the other user also answers that particular question. Once both the users answer that question, they will be displayed with new question simultaneously. I would like to dos this preferably in PHP,AJAX etc.. technologies as i can get free servers with these technologies. Some help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Try to ask more specific questions please, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check into Comet or a similar open-connection method (otherwise you're stuck with setInterval polling or something similar).  PHP may or may not be a good fit, depending on your deployment... possibly relevant discussion here:

[Using comet with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)

Comment: The Tornado web server might be something to look into.

Comment: Is there anything that can be used to do this efficiently.. like C#?