# HTML, PHP - Performant way to include php scripts (every second)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, performance, iframe

Im working on a page with a chat and some other things. These things MUST be updated every one to two seconds from my database.
I tried to do this with an ajax load.

```
function autoRefresh_div(){
    $("#chats").load("chats.php");
}
```

But yesterday we had about 100+ people on the site and each of them is loading the chat and all other stuff every second. To make it short - it crashed the webserver and we had about 50GB http-traffic in less than 30min.

Is there any other way to load my chat and all other things? Maybe **iframe**?

Comment: build a queue and send reponse to client machine. make a simple ajax request to read the queue if msg is there then get the data

Comment: You could try taking a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176937/how-to-implement-a-real-fast-web-chat-with-php

Comment: what about websockets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket?

Comment: Thanks @SzabolcsPáll websockets working very well at the moment for the chat. But I have to read some json from php script and display it to the users, too. Is there any example code to handle it?

Comment: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket 4th hit on google.