# How to flush current output in RApache?

Tags: rapache

I'm testing using RApache as an SSE (Server Sent Events) and similar (long poll, comet, etc.) back-end. I seem to be stuck on how to flush my output. Is it possible?

Here is my test R script:

```
setContentType("text/plain")

repeat{
    cat(format(Sys.time()),"\n")
    #sendBin(paste(format(Sys.time()),"\n"))
    flush(stdout())
    Sys.sleep(1)
    }
```

My Rapache.conf entry is:

```
<Location /rtest/sse>
    Options -MultiViews
    SetHandler r-handler
    RFileHandler /var/www/local/rtest/sse.r
</Location>
```

And I test it using either wget or curl:

```
wget -O - http://localhost/rtest/sse
curl http://localhost/rtest/sse
```

Both just sit there, meaning nothing is being sent.

Using `sendBin()` made no change, and neither did using `flush()`.

If I change `repeat` to `for(i in 1:5)` then it sits there for 5 seconds and then shows 5 timestamps (spaced one second apart). So, I believe everything else is working fine and this is purely a buffering issue.

**UPDATE:** Looking at this with fresh eyes after 5 months, I think I could have described the problem more clearly: the problem is that RApache appears to be buffering *all* the output, and not sending anything *until the R script exits*. To be useful for streaming it has to send data out of Apache and on to the client each time `flush()` is called, i.e. while the R script is still running.
So, my question is: is there a way to get RApache to behave like that?

**UPDATE 2** I tried adding `flush.console()` before or after the `flush(stdout())` but no difference. I also tried `setStatus(status=200L)` at the top. And I tried `SERVER$no_cache=T;SERVER$no_local_copy=T;` at the top of the script. Again it made no difference.   (Yes, none of those *should* have helped, but it never hurts to try!)

Here is a link to how PHP implements flush when it is running as an Apache module:
http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#l290
I think the key point is that there is a call to `ap_rflush(r)`. I'm guessing that RApache is not making the `ap_rflush()` call.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please post the javascript calling the  `.rhtml` file?

Comment: @Michele There is no rhtml page, I was testing using wget and curl, as shown above. (I don't want a browser confusing the issue.)

Comment: ohh I see. Sorry then, I'm trying to help but I'm probably confusing you...

Comment: Hi again, in the next message of the [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2007-August/004074.html) about `flush.console`, Simon Urbanek mention something about `TERM=dumb`. I don't know if this can help.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong MIME type. Try changing with

```
setContentType("text/event-stream")
```

EDIT1:

this is the attempt, (still unsuccessful) I mentioned in the comment below, to implement SSE in `Rook`.

```
<%
  res$header('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream')
  res$header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  res$header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
  A <- 1

  sendMessage <- function(){
    while(A<=4){
      cat("id: ", Sys.time(), "\n", "data: hello\n\n", sep="")
      A <- A+1
      flush(stdout())
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }
  }

-%>

<% sendMessage() %>
```

the `while` loop condition was supposed to be always `TRUE` but I'm having your same problem so I had to do a finite loop...

The good new is I DO have data reaching the browser. I can tell by looking, in developer tools, at the `Content-Length` in the `Response Header` section. it says 114 for the above code and you change, say, "Hello" in "Hello!" it'll say 118.

The js code is: (you'll need JQuery as well)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){

    var source = new EventSource("../R/sse.Rhtml");

    source.onopen = function(event){
      console.log("readyState: " + source.readyState);
    }

    source.onmessage = function(event){
      $("#div").append(event.data);
    };

    source.onerror = function(event){
      console.log(event);
    };

  });


});
```

So, in essence

1) The connection is open (readyState 1)

2) Buffering is still  there

3) Data (after buffering) reaches the browser but an error happens in receiving them properly.

EIDT2:

it's interesting to note that brew()ing the above .Rhtml file the output is not buffered. There must be a configuration the in the web server (both the R internal and Apache) that buffer the data flows.

As a side note, `flush` is not even needed, `cat`'s output defaults to `stout()`. So the options are:

1. Web server configuration
2. The R equivalent of the PHP `ob_flush();` which is always used in any PHP implementation I've seen. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070995/html5-server-sent-events-prototyping-ambiguous-error-and-repeated-polling) is example

Comment: Thanks Michele. `text/event-stream` for SSE, `text/plain` for all the fallback alternatives. As I'm testing from wget and curl, and not sending SSE formatted output, the mime type won't matter anyway. The issue is that the whole response is being buffered: it doesn't send anything until the R script exits.

Comment: @DarrenCook I see. Sorry for the claim. Maybe I'm wrong again (I've just started  pushing `Rook` to its limits :) ) but can you just try what happens without `repeat`?

Comment: Hello @Michele, without `repeat` it works fine (see the section about using `for(i in 1:5)`: it sits there for 5 seconds, then spits all the data out).

Comment: @Darren I see, but what I meant was without `repeat` and `for`. I 'm testing some SSE with `Rook` and I managed to have a continuous flow of data with just `cat` and `flush`.

Comment: It'd be great to see your example code/setup. (I'm writing a book on SSE, and wanted to add a brief section on how to use it with R, but so far cannot get it to work!) I'm not tied to Apache, or RApache; is Rook a standalone http server?

Comment: @DarrenCook Of course. It's not properly working yet (the `readystate` doesn't get 4, but the network tab of chrome dev tools says the data are being transferred), I'm at a good point, considering I'm using `R` as is were `PHP` via `Rook` :). I'm at work now, I'll manage to send you something this evening. Btw, Rook is an R package using the internal R web server (that one used by `R` to display help pages in a brower... no that powerful I know). I would keep using rApache, it's definitely more capable.

Comment: @DarrenCook I know you are in the terminal, but have you had a look at `?flush.console` anyway? In [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2007-August/004073.html) seems to solve buffering problems