# Reading only the last 10 lines of a text file "tail" (Jquery/Ajax/javascript or whatever)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've been searching for solutions here for a long time now, and i haven't been able to find any so far

what i need is a way to read the last 10 or so lines of a text file, which continually updates every second

i've found some possible codes in php, but then i wont be able to update the file every second.

how do i get only the last 10 lines of a text file using some sort of javascript?

Comment: is the file on your own server?

Comment: In PHP, you can spawn a "tail" process and capture its output instead of rolling out your own.

Comment: yes, the file is located in a root folder

Comment: but will a tail process update the file without updating the page

Comment: @techfoobar it should be possible, but at least I couldn't make it work. any examples?

Comment: Well can't really show an example as this involves server and client side technologies. The basic idea is to have a PHP script spawn tail (lookup exec(), passthru(), system() and related on PHP docs) and then have a JS AJAX poller that calls this periodically form the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201974/tail-f-realtime-log-via-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try using array_slice, which will return a part of an array. In this case you want it to return the last 15 lines of the array,

```
$filearr = file("filename");
$lastlines = array_slice($filearr,-10);
```

You can change -10 (-10,-15 any value you want).

Hope it works!

Comment: wouldn't that method result in slow load times, since it's a really big text file?

Comment: im looking for a way to load only the necessary lines, instead of loading the whole file on every loop.

Comment: it will not result in slow load time.

Comment: @Kautil - Of course it will affect performance if the file is huge.

Comment: @Kautil file() loads whole file in memory and converts it to an array, that's very uneffective to do every time

Comment: that was what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... maybe so, for large files:

```
$fileName = '[path_to_file]';
$file = new \SplFileObject($fileName);
$file->seek($file->getSize());

$lines = $file->key() - 1;

$file->setFlags(\SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$counter = 0;
$records = 100;
$seek = $lines - $records;

$file->seek($seek);

$return = array();
while ($counter++ < $records) {
    try {
        $line = $file->fgets();
        $return[] = $line;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: that's php thou,
how do i get it to update the page dynamically

Comment: i've seen the while loop, but do i have to put it after them </html> to keep the page loading, or would an iframe be the solution?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    // use ajax here with this solution
});

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ajax, but isn't this php?

Comment: Ajax in jQuery is very simple, look for example:

$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'[path_to_your_script]',
            dataType:'text',
            data:{
                // params
            },
            success:function (msg) {
              // on success
            },
            complete:function (r) {
              // on complete
            },
            error:function (error) {
              // on error
            }
        });

Comment: so ajax calls a php file, which then returns the data to the ajax/jquery which then puts the retrieved data into the div?

Comment: yes, return array and add id for div and than $('#[id_value]').html('your html here'); after processing data from your array

look here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: is there anyway to send an attribute like for example the file name when calling the script?

Comment: Yes, but better practice is set the filename in PHP script, enybody can set the filename in JS and get for example /etc/passwd file content, set this in script.

Comment: the thing is that i need to show a different text for depending on the user id

but i guess that's easily done in php using sessions :)

Comment: Yes, but data will be not actual.

Comment: how do i handle the returned data?

Comment: Everything is in jQuery documentation.

Comment: this code just returns [object Object] :     


`var jqxhr = $.get("/user/server/load_file_part.php", function() {
    alert("data retrieved: "+jqxhr+"");`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find the correct answer here, so i started a new question where i'm more specific with what i want

[Reading ONLY the last 50 lines of a large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465886/reading-only-the-last-50-lines-of-a-large-text-file)

Comment: You should not have reposted. Instead, you should have edited the question to 1) make more clear what you want and 2) generate some activity (the editing) so it will reappear on the front page. If you would have done that you wouldn't have to post another duplicate.