# How does gmail chat send data to users without long-polling?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, long-polling, polling

I have been fiddling with a chat program for some time now.

Polling with AJAX has been successful, but it sends a request to the server every second, which seems too expensive to me, not to mention every 1000ms is slow these days.

Long-polling has been UNSUCCESSFUL. I found that I CAN do a long-polling request on my server (Apache) but that if I have a long-polling request running, the rest of the webpage is rendered 'dead'. I can't click in a text box or type or whathaveyou.

I now know that this is because Apache uses multiple threads for a long-polling request and thus consumes a lot of resource, unlike other server types.

My questions:

1.How can I create the same "instant message functionality" without long-polling (or how can I functionally and successfully do long-polling on Apache?). I just need

`When (someone sends a message and thus a file on server changes) {send data to all users;},` should be easy enough right?

I notice that facebook does long-polling for the client (in Firebug), BUT
Gmail chat apparently does not and yet has the same functionality?!

2.How does gmail chat do it?

I have read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) about Comet and [this article](http://www.ekhoury.com/blog/2007/02/07/ajax-alternatives-gmail-choice/) and watched an [informative video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Comet-DWR-Joe-Walker), where the speaker says this can be done with PHP/JS, and have a good understand of the IDEA, I just want the CODE..

Comment: Yep, there is also COMET technologies, (like APE (AJAX Push Engine))

Comment: "I now know that this is because Apache uses multiple threads for a long-polling request and thus consumes a lot of resource, unlike other server types." ... That has nothing to do with the ability to interact with the page in the browser.

Comment: Further to the above take a look at http://socket.io/ for a cross-browser solution

Comment: @SLaks, Yes, it does, clearly, because when I have a long-polling request pending even using usleep() in the 'waiting' PHP script, the page becomes 'unclickable' and 'untypable'

Comment: @khanahk: Unless you're using evil synchronous AJAX (don't), that won't happen.

Comment: This could be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a long-polling PHP and Apache workable solution. And it is a charm.

http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

All I had to do was `set_time_limit(0);` in backend.php and all is as it should be.