# What does a long polling script look like, and how to implement it,

Tags: php, long-polling

all. I have a site with a small chatroom, and my users are increasingly eating my bandwidth, and after having searched for some miracle, I finally stumped onto something sexy:) called, **Long Polling** from what I understand,

> it is a simple method that is supposed to keep the connection betwe en
>   server/client UN-interapted for a longer period of time, and by doing
>   so reduces the need for continues requests by 90%.

Now, I could be wrong. but, how is this "Simple" thing created. Below, you can see my chat script, I created from a tutorial using Jquery. It works fine, but it is without longpolling capabilities.

Here is the [PHP](http://pastebin.com/mKDGUNxE) and [Javascript](http://pastebin.com/BsHzuK7F)  code (I can't paste them here, as they are too long).

Now, the question is how do I inject the long poll script into my already built codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read your code, but here is a tiny example:

```
function waitForNotification() {
    $.ajax(url, {
        timeout: 60000,
        success: function(e) {
            //do want you want with e
            //and call function again:
            waitForNotification();
        }
    });
}
```

On the server side, you need to collect all ajax (on `url`) requests, and release the response only when a new message has been posted. Obviously, the server side method is harder to implement and totally depends on your server architecture (you can use a COMET implementation).

If you implement it by yourself, be careful, in fact a new message `m` may be posted while the client is processing the `success` event (and misses the `m` notification).

Configure your ajax request as you wish (handle other events).

Interesting:

- [COMET and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603201/using-comet-with-php)
- [CometD](http://cometd.org/) (COMET interface for PHP)